# How can I return the distance out of the Google Directions API for later use?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am trying to calculate  the distance between 2 points on the map, and it works pretty good.
The problem is that I am trying to make the function return the distance, so that I can use it, not only display it.
Here is my code:

```
function getDistance(origin, destination){

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var request = {
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request,function(response){
        var d = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
        //alert(d);
    }); 


}
```

The thing is that I want not olny to be able to alert the result, but also to use it in order to, say order some locations based on the distance from the user, and using this kind of function, I don;'t see how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare your `var d` outside your `function`, then you could use it later

```
var d;

function getDistance(origin, destination) {
    // ...

    d = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
}
```

You can now use `d` in another method or elsewhere in your code.